# Writing an ActiveRecord adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hbase

I'd like to write my own [ActiveRecord adapter](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/) for the [HBase database](http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/) since none currently exist. However, I've been searching for a while online and can't find any good resources on how to write an ActiveRecord adapter. How would you go about doing this, or are there any links you can recommend?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is [go to the source](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/1c11437a32a973fa9b521c32caa7256f9772acd7/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters).

The rails trunk has adapters for mysql, postgres and sqlite, which you could base your adapter on. `abstract_adapter.rb` is pretty short and fairly straight forward to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Rhino](http://qslack.com/proj/rhino).