# ActiveAdmin without ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activeadmin

Is there a way to make ActiveAdmin show information from a resource that isn't a database?

I have a model that's instantiated from JSON received remotely. I would like to get ActiveAdmin to show this information.

If I seed the database, ActiveAdmin will show the same number of records that I have in the seed file. When I comment out the seed, it shows nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will have to change ActiveAdmin code, and will not be trivial.

Active admin [depends on rails](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/activeadmin.gemspec) which depends on active record.

It also extensively [use active record features](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/1930da57a656dfe82607c2985855ba17813c6c29/features/step_definitions/factory_steps.rb) on the code.

The best path to go is to write a db adapter for Rails using your API. There is [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149237/writing-an-activerecord-adapter) here that addresses how to create a DB adapter.